# Is there a custom version of jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cordova

I'm about to use jQuery in a Phonegap application and my question is - is there a custom variant of the jQuery? ... For example, when you download the jQuery UI - you choose which "parts" of the whole UI to be included in the package you're downloading. So, is there something like this in the jQuery itself?

(Cause for now I'm gonna use the Ajax, the JSON parsing and the selectors, and maybe the Bind, Live, etc. events. For animations I'm using CSS 3, so I don't need the animation stuff in the jQuery, and I think that if I strip the unnecessary things - the whole JS will be much lighter than if I use the whole jQuery.)

Regards,
Peter

PS: And also - now I'm using JSON2 for parsing JSON, iScroll for the scrolling features, and the only big thing I'm about to use jQuery is the unification of the Ajax ... so if you have a better suggestion - I'll be glad to hear it.

Comment: You could use mootools instead (http://mootools.net/), it's modular and you can choose your components much like jQuery UI. You could also your jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Have you look at [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)? Its optimized for mobile and includes basic theming components that are somewhat similar to jQuery UI.

Answer (score 1):

May be this what you are looking for

http://www.servicestack.net/jqbuilder/

This let's you choose what exactly you need from jQuery and build a custom lib from the required list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about size, use [zepto](http://zeptojs.com).  It is designed to be pretty much jquery-api compatibile (except that it currently doesn't return a jqXHR on ajax functions so if you are doing modern jQuery ajax you will have to rewrite some.  It's 8K compressed-gzipped (compared to the 32K of jQuery) and only 44K uncompressed (compared to the 232K of jQuery).  It takes advantage of modern webkit browser functionality and doesn't have the bloat required by IE and older browser support that jQuery does.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately both zepto and the customized jQuery variant don't have the parsing JSON functionality. ( $.parseJSON() in jQuery )
Which means that I'll still have to use the JSON2 library as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you worried about size (jquery-1.7.2.min.js is only 93KB)?

Your question does not mention the design of the app (e.g. Are you simply using PhoneGap to launch an external web site or is it all self contained?).

The jQuery file will be released along with the App as a resource of the App until you leave the 'App' for say an external link (link that opens within the web view control of the app and not the native browser (e.g. IE, Safari, etc.)).